# OCX in WPF application .net 4.0 - 4.5

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, ocx

I have to use an ocx in an WPF application. If i make a new project under the .net framework 4.5 It works perfectly.

But if i try to make an application in any other .net framework VisualStudio gives the error "Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))" 
I tried to fix it with regsvr32 but it still doens't work.

How do i fix this so i can make an .net 4.0 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i fixed the problem the only thing i had to do was change the debug/release mode to x86.